# Rails switch database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql

I've found info explaining how to set up a Rails application from the beginning using a PostgreSQL database. But I have an application already built. Any advice on steps to take to change my existing application to use PostgreSQL rather than SQLite?

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Rails 6+ you can do this:

`rails db:system:change --to=postgresql`

where `postgresql` would be the DB you want.

This was enabled by this [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34832).

Comment: But when I type this command, it says "invalid option: --to=postgresql".

Answer (score 3):

Install the pg gem in your Gemfile

gem 'pg'

change the database.yml file to use your database ex.

```
adapter: postgresql
database: db_name
pool:
timeout:
host: localhost
username: username
password: password
```

db_name, username, and password values are what you have set your postgresql database too

Comment: After doing this, I had to restart my rails server

Answer (score 1):

One point to note, making such a switch would not account for any data records in the SQLite database itself merely the database structure.  If you want to migrate from one database to another AND you had a lot of data in the old database that you want to bring with to the new database, you can use the `yaml_db` gem.

This would allow to you export the data into a YAML dump file, switch database adapter, create and migrate the database, then import the YAML dump back into the new database.

I actually recently posted a [YouTube video on this exact topic](https://youtu.be/NWjvKCP1AxY), in case you are more of a visual learner like myself.